# Get all Cluster Objects from Google Maps in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps Angular library here: https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps

Trying to create a "Toggle Clusters" feature with my existing clustering code:

```
<google-map 
center="map.center" 
zoom="map.zoom"
draggable="true"
events="mapEventObject"
control="googleMap">

<markers 
    models="markers" coords="'coord'" 
    doCluster="map.cluster"
    clusterEvents="map.clusterEvents"
    events="markerEventObject">
</markers>
```

```
$scope.markers = [{
   coord: {
       latitude: -38,
       longitude: 50
   }
}]
```

The issue is that $scope.markers is an array and not the actual MarkerClusterer Object. Therefore, I am unable to call .removeMarkers() method without the object for the "toggling" effect.

Using Angular, how do I get the MarkerClusterer objects on the map? I could not find a .getAllClusters() method or anything of that like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who run into the same problem, the issue is covered here: https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps/issues/561 and has not been pushed to the latest master branch.  To fix, use the current "develop" branch ( as of July 2014).